# Need to change the error name(you must enter a value) as of (Need a value).How?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

Need to change the error name(you must enter a value) as of (Need a value).How?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a standard required field on a standard page layout you cannot overwrite or change this using a validation rule (the required field test is run before the validation rule).

The only way to do this is by writing a Visualforce page and displaying a custom error message. You will need to have the re-render run immediately as well for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validation rule.

Comment: I used but Which Formula we have to use in v alidation rule.